# DataFrame to scatter chart only plots 2 points

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `dataframe` that has time as a key, with lat, lon as values, and it can either contain 0 or a position:

```
Index  Latitude     Longitude
00:00  0.0          0.0
00:01  -23.4649225  -46.6964685
00:02  -23.4650154  -46.6965732
...
23:58  0.0          0.0
23:59  0.0          0.0
```

when I try to plot a scatter chart it gives me only two points [scatterplottemp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHaLh.png)

I tried transforming it in two differents `lists` and `series`, no result, I know for a fact that I can transform them into a `dictionary` and get my result, but I`d rather not do that.

```
plt.scatter(df['Latitude'],df['Longitude'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the dataframe actually has more than two points in it? From the snippet you posted I can only see (0.0, 0.0) and two points around (-23.46, -46.696) which would would probably overlap completely on your scatterplot

Comment: Maybe all points are within narrow margins of (-23, -46) that they appear to be one point because of the scaling from the other point (0,0). Have you tried plotting it without (0,0)?

Comment: Yes it has, over 1000 is position, the rest is 0

Comment: @Piinthesky this issue has crossed my mind, but I don`t how to work around it... the position 0.0 is necessary

Comment: @Piinthesky Yeah! It works out fine thanks, but do you know any way to bypass the 0?

Comment: You want to include the zero as a reference or why does this point have to appear in your graph? Usually your axis labelling tells the viewer, where you are.

Comment: No actually I don't! This is working fine, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a dataframe that has time as a key, with lat, lon as values, and it can either contain 0 or a position:

```
Index  Latitude     Longitude
00:00  0.0          0.0
00:01  -23.4649225  -46.6964685
00:02  -23.4650154  -46.6965732
...
23:58  0.0          0.0
23:59  0.0          0.0
```

when I try to plot a scatter chart it gives me only two points scatterplottemp

I tried transforming it in two differents lists and series, no result, I know for a fact that I can transform them into a dictionary and get my result, but I`d rather not do that.

```
plt.scatter(df['Latitude'],df['Longitude'])
plt.show()
```

SOLUTION PROVIDED BY @Piinthesky:

filter the 0

```
df = df[(df['Latitude'] != 0) | (df['Longitude'] != 0)]
df.plot.scatter(x = 'Latitude',y = 'Longitude')
```

Comment: In case you have to include a second point cloud (e.g. points really scattered around (0, 0), which need to be shown in the same graph), you can adapt this [matplotlib example for a broken axis](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)

Comment: Err, this is not valid syntax in my interpreter. I would use `df = df[(df['Latitude'] != 0) | (df['Longitude'] != 0)]`

Comment: The operator `<>` works in my setting only in Python 2.x equivalent to `!=`, in Python 3 it throws a syntax error. [Get ready for the future!](https://pythonclock.org/)